# Shell script to check if status in returned output of command is OK or not

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a shell script which will check if the backup was successful or not from the following output to send the alert via mail:

```
Server standby:
    PostgreSQL: OK
    is_superuser: OK
    PostgreSQL streaming: OK
    wal_level: Failed
    replication slot: OK
    directories: OK
    retention policy settings: OK
    backup maximum age: OK (no last_backup_maximum_age provided)
    compression settings: OK
    failed backups: OK (there are 0 failed backups)
    minimum redundancy requirements: OK (have 96 backups, expected at least 0)
    ssh: OK (PostgreSQL server)
    pg_receivexlog: OK
    pg_receivexlog compatible: OK
    receive-wal running: OK
    archiver errors: OK
```

Below is the simple shell script which does the work:

```
#!/bin/bash

OUT="Server standby:
    PostgreSQL: OK
    is_superuser: OK
    PostgreSQL streaming: Failed
    wal_level: OK
    replication slot: OK
    directories: OK
    retention policy settings: OK
    backup maximum age: OK (no last_backup_maximum_age provided)
    compression settings: OK
    failed backups: OK (there are 0 failed backups)
    minimum redundancy requirements: OK (have 96 backups, expected at least 0)
    ssh: OK (PostgreSQL server)
    pg_receivexlog: OK
    pg_receivexlog compatible: OK
    receive-wal running: OK
    archiver errors: OK"

if [ "`echo "$OUT" | sed -n '1!p' | grep -v 'OK'`" = "" ]
then
        echo "Backup successful & nothing failed"
        else
        echo "$OUT" | sed -n '1!p' | grep -v 'OK'
    fi
```

**Output:**
./check2.sh
    PostgreSQL streaming: Failed

Is there any better way to check using iteration or array?
Something like this I have tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

OUT="Server standby:
    PostgreSQL: OK
    is_superuser: OK
    PostgreSQL streaming: Failed
    wal_level: OK
    replication slot: OK
    directories: OK
    retention policy settings: OK
    backup maximum age: OK (no last_backup_maximum_age provided)
    compression settings: OK
    failed backups: OK (there are 0 failed backups)
    minimum redundancy requirements: OK (have 96 backups, expected at least 0)
    ssh: OK (PostgreSQL server)
    pg_receivexlog: OK
    pg_receivexlog compatible: OK
    receive-wal running: OK
    archiver errors: OK"

#FAIL=$(echo "$OUT" | sed 's/:.*//' | sed -n '1!p')

for status in $(echo "$OUT" | cut -d ":" -f 2 | sed -n '1!p' | awk '{print $1}' )
do
        if [ "$status" = 'OK' ]
        then
        echo "$status"
        else
                echo "$FAIL "-" $status"
        fi
done
```

Comment: As an aside, using all-caps variable names is bad form (allows overwriting variables meaningful to the system by mistake). Consider lowercase names for user-defined variables where not using them already.

Comment: BTW, if you *really* want to iterate over lines as they're read, see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
egrep -v '^Server standby:$|: OK|^$' <<<"$OUT"
```

...will return only the line:

```
    wal_level: Failed
```

---

Thus, this can be as simple as:

```
failures=$(grep -E -v '^Server standby:$|: OK|^$' <<<"$OUT")

if [[ $failures ]]; then
  printf '%s\n' "$failures"
else
  echo "Backup successful and nothing failed"
fi
```

---

That said, if you want each line of the output to be added to an array (to be able to count them by checking array length, for example), that's easily done:

```
mapfile -t failures < <(grep -E -v '^Server standby:$|: OK|^$' <<<"$OUT")

if (( ${#failures[@]} == 0 )); then
  echo "No failures"
else
  echo "Failures seen:"
  printf ' - %s\n' "${failures[@]}"
fi
```

...I'm hard-pressed to call that simpler, though.

Comment: I have already done this using
if [ "`echo "$OUT" | sed -n '1!p' | grep -v 'OK'`" = "" ]
which will return all lines without 'OK'.

I am looking for better solution using iteration or something else.
Or skipping 'OK' is the only best solution?

Comment: I took your question to be asking for simpler code. Is that *not* what you're asking? (It might help to edit the question to be more clear about what it is that's actually being asked).

Comment: This looks like a clean solution to me, and it seems to be answering the question. Good job @CharlesDuffy

Comment: This seems overly complicated.  If you just do `if grep -v OK >&2` (after dealing with the header line appropriately), you get the relevant lines on the error stream for free.  There's no need to try to track them in an array.  Sure, doing so gives you the ability to massage the error into a form you might consider more friendly, but chances are good that you'll wind up suppressing information rather than adding clarity at the expense of needless complexity.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, I added the array approach because the OP explicitly asked for it. I don't think it's a good idea either.